# How do I get the annotated window in Visual Studio 2015 to automatically go to the line I was just viewing?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, tfs

When I'm editing a file in Visual Studio 2015 and I select **File->Source Control->Annotated** the new window with the annotated file is at line #1.  How can I get it to match the line number I'm correctly at without using the **Go To Line** dialog box.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know no such a feature or an extension can achieve that for now.

Generally, the Annotation and file editing have different focus.

**Go To Line** is enough to navigate to the specific line with the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>

For the Annotation you can use below shortcuts to move the region:

- Tfs Annotate Move Next Region <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd>
- Tfs Annotate Move Previous Region <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd>